# How to search based on contains using DynamicFilterBuilder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my project currently i have implemented multiple searching using below function code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        var predicate = new DynamicFilterBuilder<T>();

        foreach (var item in searchCriteria.filters)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.key))
            {
                if (item.key == "CreatedOn")
                    predicate.And(item.key, DynamicExpressions.FilterOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual, DateTime.ParseExact(item.value.ToString() + " 00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null))
                    .And(item.key, DynamicExpressions.FilterOperator.LessThanOrEqual, DateTime.ParseExact(item.value.ToString() + " 23:59:59", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null));
                else
                    predicate.And(item.key,
                      DynamicExpressions.FilterOperator.Contains, item.value);
            }
        }

        return source.Where(predicate.Build());
    }
```

But it's working only like Case sensitive means i need to pass exactly Name ex : "Data" if i passed "data" it's not returning anything so can someone help me on this ?

Comment: What package are the DynamicExpressions and DynamicFilterBuilder from?  Is there a "LIKE" filter operator?

Comment: @Christopher Hamkins No there is no "LIKE" filter available DynamicExpressions  is new feature.

Comment: @check below link for package and details https://github.com/zHaytam/DynamicExpressions

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lower case conversion here and compare with a lowercase like below:

```
  if (item.key.ToLower() == "createdon")
    {
         //Your stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am searching based on  item.value  for me if condition working fine for date just problem with name like if i am passing "Dnyanesh" then working but if i passed "dnyanesh" returning empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The package from zHaytam mentioned in the comment ( [github.com/zHaytam/DynamicExpressions](http://%20github.com/zHaytam/DynamicExpressions)) is open source on GitHub so we can see that in its implementation (Class DynamicExpressions), the expressions are delegating to Linq expressions:

```
private static Expression CreateFilter(MemberExpression prop, FilterOperator op, ConstantExpression constant)
        {
            return op switch
            {
                FilterOperator.Equals => Expression.Equal(prop, constant),
                FilterOperator.GreaterThan => Expression.GreaterThan(prop, constant),
                FilterOperator.LessThan => Expression.LessThan(prop, constant),
                FilterOperator.Contains => Expression.Call(prop, _containsMethod, PrepareConstant(constant)),
                FilterOperator.StartsWith => Expression.Call(prop, _startsWithMethod, PrepareConstant(constant)),
                FilterOperator.EndsWith => Expression.Call(prop, _endsWithMethod, PrepareConstant(constant)),
                FilterOperator.DoesntEqual => Expression.NotEqual(prop, constant),
                FilterOperator.GreaterThanOrEqual => Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(prop, constant),
                FilterOperator.LessThanOrEqual => Expression.LessThanOrEqual(prop, constant),
                _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
            };
        }
```

and the `containsMethod` uses the version `public bool Contains (string value);` of `string.Contains`:

```
        private static readonly MethodInfo _containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"
            , new Type[] { typeof(string) });
```

To make the "Contains" method become case-insensitive, I think you can download and modify zHaytam's code:

In method `DynamicExpressions` modify the initialization expression of `_containsMethod`  to reference the `public bool Contains (string value, StringComparison comparisonType)` version of `string.Contains`:

```
        private static readonly MethodInfo _containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"
            , new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
```

and modify the `CreateFilter` method to provide the additional parameter to ignore case:

```
FilterOperator.Contains => Expression.Call(prop, _containsMethod, PrepareConstant(constant), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I have download and modify zHaytam's code also raise pr .